# Display CSV file in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf, csv

Here is my code:

```
public String download(){
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
       log.info("Entered for downloading: ");
    }
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
    try{
        List<TableController> list = fetchTechniciansList();
        Iterator<TableController> iter = list.iterator();
        ServletOutputStream out = null;
        response.reset();`
        response.setContentType("application/csv"); 
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private"); 
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "none");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=\""
            + "technician_list.csv" + "\"");
        out=response.getOutputStream();
        out.write("First Name".getBytes());
        out.write(',');
        out.write("Last Name".getBytes());
        out.write(',');
        out.write("User ID".getBytes());
        out.write('\n');
        Integer i=0; 
        while(iter.hasNext()) {             
            out.write(list.get(i).getFirst_name().getBytes());
            out.write(',');
            out.write(list.get(i).getBean_last_name().getBytes());
            out.write(',');
            out.write(list.get(i).getUser_id().toString().getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            i++;            
            iter.next();
        }       
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        facesContext.responseComplete();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        log.error("downloading error");
        log.info("Exited");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have command link in HTML :

```
<h:commandLink value="Download Technician List" action="#{tableControllerBean.download}" style="float:right" target="_blank"></h:commandLink>
```

which calls this `download()` method. The problem is that the list opens directly in Excel but not in IE. I am using IE 8 with Windows 7. How can I get this to open in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Found the following page with instructions how to show CVS and XLS in IE. The instructions are for XP but may give you some clue...

http://www.winxptutor.com/iedocs.htm

You could also try another ContentType, e.g. text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

What a user agent does with the content it receives when making a request to a server is 100% up to the user agent. In a nutshell, other than advise your users on how to configure their system to treat *.csv files as text and display them in the page, there is not much you can do.

That said, one thing to check is the media type you are sending back in the header. Many browsers will handle responses differently depending on the media type.

Lastly, if displaying the content in the browser is critical, you may consider annotating the CSV content with HTML + CSS to make it display the way you want. Browsers are designed to handle HTML and, in general, tend to pass other content to other more appropriate applications installed in the system. In many cases, depending on what your users want to do with the CSV content, an actual spreadsheet program may be *much* more useful to them, since it has much more functionality than a browser can easily provide.

Comment: I could not understand what u mean to say . How will I know the media type ?

Comment: You, as the server sending the response, set the media type in the Content Type header of the http response.